# SimpleJdbcTemplate for both insert and update

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I am using SimpleJdbcTemplate batchUpdate method to do batch inserts and updates. Currently since I do not know if it is an insert or update I query the database first. Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

No - not really.

But an alternative scheme you might consider is to do like some banks: Do only INSERTs. Then you use proper SELECT statements to select only the most recent version of each row.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have done... Option 1 - Insert one row at a time and if it fails update Option 2 - Get existing database values and split the data that needs to be saved into insert and update lists and finally do batch insert and update. Did some check to see which was quicker and I realized that Option 2 was quicker. I still think spring needs an insertOrUpdateBatch method :-)